# What happened to Salesforce Technical Architect journey books?

Tags: certification

Does anybody know what happened to https://www.inkling.com/store/salesforce-university/ ?

When I access the page I don't see anything; searching in inkling store also doesn't bring relevant results... Books still seem to be included in Google's (cached) search results but there's no actual content.

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:cHdYdgQgSy8J:https://www.inkling.com/store/book/salesforce-application-architecture/+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

[image: Google cache snapshot]

There used to be books available to assist you with "[Architect yourney](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/11/new-salesforce-architect-journey.html)" and "Designer exams".

I don't think they ever were available as PDFs, it was something you can read online / via smartphone app but still - I feel I'm bit screwed now planning to attack next exam...

---

Possibly related problem: http://resourceondemand.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/SGCertifiedIntegrationArchitectureDesigner.pdf mentions this on page 4:

> To prepare for this exam, Salesforce University recommends at least
>   one year of Integration Architecture experience and familiarity with
>   the Integration Architecture eBook in the Architect Academy.
>   Salesforce University recommends the following instructor-led and
>   online courses, and other resources to guide your study:
>
> - Architect Academy Resources – http://www.salesforce.com/campaigns/success-services/architectacademy.jsp

that's also a dead link for me. Awesome.

Any idea whom we can contact or whatever?

Comment: Almost non of the links in this entire page work, either on the question or the answers.

Comment: They largely got converted to trailmixes (compare https://metillium.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/RGCertifiedDataArchitectureandManagementDesigner.pdf with https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/users/strailhead/trailmixes/architect-data-architecture-and-management. If you Google for pdf names you can still see some copies lying around on blogs but content might be outdated!, try to use live version. Best ones became real documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_intro_overview.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce has assembled all certification related guides under this main link

[Certification link](http://certification.salesforce.com/credentialoverview): http://certification.salesforce.com/credentialoverview

Click on left side "Architects" menu for each respective certifications.

Now all the documents are pdf formats, so we can refer them at offline too.

[image: overview]

Here is the Application Architect [self-directed resource guide](http://certification.salesforce.com/RG_CertifiedApplicationArchitect.pdf)

Comment: Heh, thank you :) "Darkest under the lamp" I guess

Comment: Bless you mate. I almost had a heart attack.

Comment: Almost non of the links in this entire page work, either on the question or the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Found some official statement from SF, buried deep in Certification FAQ:

http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Frequently-Asked-Questions-Salesforce-Architect-Program/

> Q: I cannot find the ebooks in Inkling.  Where are they located?
>
> A: We
>   are in the process of migrating our ebooks over to Trailhead and they
>   are currently located on our Certification website under the Architect
>   section. Each PDF can be found with the associated certification that
>   it references.

Comment: Almost non of the links in this entire page work, either on the question or the answers.